# Getting this code to work in Multisite

Tags: multisite, wp-cron

I'd like to run this code via cron on multisite. When I use the admin_init hook the code executes and works perfectly, deleting the blogs, however when I set it as a cron, and then run the event with the WP Crontrol plugin, the blogs don't get deleted. What gives?

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'remove_blogs_activation' );
    /**
     * On activation, set a time, frequency and name of an action hook to be scheduled.
     */
    function remove_blogs_activation() {
        wp_schedule_event( 1386979200, 'daily', 'remove_blogs_hook' );
    }


    add_action( 'remove_blogs_hook', 'remove_blogs_daily' );

    function remove_blogs_daily() { 
        $all_blogs = wp_get_sites();    

        foreach ( $all_blogs as $key => $val ) {

            $blogs_to_keep = array( '1','2' );
            if ( ! in_array( $val['blog_id'], $blogs_to_keep ) ) {
                wpmu_delete_blog( $val['blog_id'], true );          
            }

        }
    }
```

The new code I'm using, to also clear the users:

```
    <?php



    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpchat_clear_sites_activation' );
    /**
     * On activation, set a time, frequency and name of an action hook to be scheduled.
     */
    function wpchat_clear_sites_activation() {
        wp_schedule_event( 1386979200, 'daily', 'daily_clear_sites_hook' );
    }


    add_action( 'daily_clear_sites_hook', 'wpchat_clear_out_sites_daily' );
    /**
     * Clear out the sites and users
     */
    function wpchat_clear_out_sites_daily() { 
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );

        if( ! function_exists( 'wpmu_delete_blog' ) ) return;

            $users_to_keep = array( '1','4','43' );

        $blogs_to_keep = array( '1','4' );

        $all_sites = wp_get_sites();    

        // Remove all blogs except for the main blog and the template blog
        foreach ( $all_sites as $key => $val ) {

            $users = get_users( array( 'blog_id' => $val['blog_id'], 'fields' => ID ) );

            // Remove all users except for the test site admins
            foreach ( $users as $user) { 

                if ( ! in_array( $user, $users_to_keep ) ) {
                    wp_delete_user( $user['ID'] );
                }
            }

            if ( ! in_array( $val['blog_id'], $blogs_to_keep ) ) {
                wpmu_delete_blog( $val['blog_id'], true );          
            }

        }
    }

    register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpchat_clear_sites_deactivation' );
    /**
     * On deactivation, remove all functions from the scheduled action hook.
     */
    function wpchat_clear_sites_deactivation() {
        wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'daily_clear_sites_hook' );
    }
```

Comment: First of all, you should place this line of code `$blogs_to_keep = array( '1','2' );` before `foreach`. There is no need to create the array on each looping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Problem:

When `wp-cron.php` is called, it includes only:

```
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-load.php' );
```

so the problem you are facing is that

```
wpmu_delete_blog()
```

is **undefined** when you call it from your `remove_blogs_daily()` function.

### Possible Solution:

You therefore need to add this line:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );
```

into your code to fix that.

Try this for example:

```
function remove_blogs_daily()
{ 
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );

    if( ! function_exists( 'wpmu_delete_blog' ) ) return;

    $all_blogs = wp_get_sites();    

    $blogs_to_keep = array( 1, 2 );

    foreach ( $all_blogs as $key => $val )
    {
        if ( ! in_array( $val['blog_id'], $blogs_to_keep ) ) 
        {
            wpmu_delete_blog( $val['blog_id'], TRUE );          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to remove the users of these blogs too, trying this code but it's not working, can you help?

$users_to_keep = array( '1','4','43' );
  $users = get_users( array( 'blog_id' => $val['blog_id'] ) );
  
  // Remove all users except for the test site admins
  foreach ( $users as $user ) { 
   if ( ! in_array( $user['ID'], $users_to_keep ) ) {
    wp_delete_user( $user['ID'] );
   }
  }

Comment: You might have to include another file to use  `wp_delete_user()`, try for example: `require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );`

Comment: Still not working, updated the new version of the code I'm using above, can you check?

Comment: I think it would be better served as a new question ;-) (might be more files to include)

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130705/deleting-sites-and-users-automatically-in-multisite