# Deleting sites and users automatically in multisite

Tags: multisite

I am trying to create a scheduled delete of sites and their users in WordPress multisite. The code I made is successful in deleting the sites but not the users, can anyone offer a fix?

```
<?php
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpchat_clear_sites_activation' );
/**
 * On activation, set a time, frequency and name of an action hook to be scheduled.
 */
function wpchat_clear_sites_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event( 1386979200, 'daily', 'daily_clear_sites_hook' );
}


add_action( 'daily_clear_sites_hook', 'wpchat_clear_out_sites_daily' );
/**
 * Clear out the sites and users
 */
function wpchat_clear_out_sites_daily() { 
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );

    if( ! function_exists( 'wpmu_delete_blog' ) ) return;

        $users_to_keep = array( '1','4','43' );

    $blogs_to_keep = array( '1','4' );

    $all_sites = wp_get_sites();    

    // Remove all blogs except for the main blog and the template blog
    foreach ( $all_sites as $key => $val ) {

        $users = get_users( array( 'blog_id' => $val['blog_id'], 'fields' => ID ) );

        // Remove all users except for the test site admins
        foreach ( $users as $user) { 

            if ( ! in_array( $user['ID'], $users_to_keep ) ) {
                wpmu_delete_user( $user['ID'] );
            }
        }

        if ( ! in_array( $val['blog_id'], $blogs_to_keep ) ) {
            wpmu_delete_blog( $val['blog_id'], true );          
        }

    }
}
```

The sites are deleted via cron or via direct function call, so cron is not the issue here, it's the way I'm trying to delete users.

Comment: Does the code work not in cron context?

Comment: Keep in mind that users are shared between sites. So if you delete it anywhere, s/he has to add a new account when visiting another site of your network.

Comment: @Rarst added more info.

Comment: Basically I need to clear out all users apart from the 3 specified in the array.

Comment: I think I see a bug.  This line: `if ( ! in_array( $user['ID'], $users_to_keep ) ) {`

Comment: @user42826 Indeed, fixed that however now I get all the non needed sites deleted but their users remain.

Comment: Wait, I was wrong! All your references to `$user['ID']` should be `$user`.  I didnt see that you called get_users() with a specific field to return.

Comment: Oh ok, users still aren't being deleted though.

Comment: I think the code is not doing what you think it does.  The code you have listed above: iterates through all blogs, it grabs users that are defined for each blog, and removes the users from all of WP.  Note that you may have a population of users that do not belong to any site!  Those users will not be deleted!

Comment: Indeed it's not. How can I modify it to delete all sites and users except the ones indicated in the arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note** -- as Kaiser rightly points out in his comment, Multisite shares users between sites. If you remove one, you remove her from *all* the sites in your network. If that's not your intent, then look into [`remove_user_from_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_user_from_blog).

---

Instead of `wp_delete_user()`, use [`wpmu_delete_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpmu_delete_user). Looking at [the source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-admin/includes/ms.php#L158), `wpmu_delete_user()` first checks if the user in question is a user on any sites in the network, removes her if she is, cleans up any links and metadata associated with her account, and then finally deletes the user as you'd expect.

[This WordPress support thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_delete_user-bug-in-multisite?replies=16) is what pointed me in this direction.

#### Re-assigning posts before deleting the user

From the [source of `wpmu_delete_user()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-admin/includes/ms.php#L158):

```
do_action( 'wpmu_delete_user', $id );

$blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $id );

if ( ! empty( $blogs ) ) {
        foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) {
                switch_to_blog( $blog->userblog_id );
                remove_user_from_blog( $id, $blog->userblog_id );

                $post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_author = %d", $id ) );
                foreach ( (array) $post_ids as $post_id ) {
                        wp_delete_post( $post_id );
                }

                // Clean links
                $link_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT link_id FROM $wpdb->links WHERE link_owner = %d", $id ) );

                if ( $link_ids ) {
                        foreach ( $link_ids as $link_id )
                                wp_delete_link( $link_id );
                }

                restore_current_blog();
        }
}
```

So the default action when deleting a user programmatically is to find and remove her posts from every site (blog) where she's a user.  However, there is an action hook that runs just before, conveniently named `wpmu_delete_user`.  So you should be able to programmatically re-assign the to-be-deleted user's posts *before* you delete her:

```
add_action( 'wpmu_delete_user', 'wpse130705_reassign_posts' );
function wpse130705_reassign_posts( $id ) {
    // $id should contain the user's ID
    $blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $id );
    $assign_to = 99; // some other user's ID; you'll have to work out what this will be
    if( ! empty( $blogs ) ) {
        foreach( $blogs as $blog ) {
            switch_to_blog( $blog->userblog_id );
            $post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( 
                $wpdb->prepare( 
                    "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_author=%d", $id 
                )
            );
            if( $post_ids ) {
                foreach( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
                    $wpdb->update( 
                        $table = $wpdb->posts,
                        $data  = array( 'post_author' => $assign_to ),
                        $where = array( 'post_author' => $id ),
                        $format = '%d',
                        $where_format = '%d'
                    );
                }
            }
            restore_current_blog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed that, however for some reason the code is removing the posts and pages of the main site in the multisite (id 1) and also the superadmin user (id 1). Any idea why?

Comment: Updated my answer to try to fix that.